# Transit Objects to centralize instances

Tags: c++

What do you think of this concept:
A number of classes exist in a project, some of them are singletons and want to be shared throughout the codebase. Including each required header and creating a dedicated pointer call in subclasses can be a hassle. The idea: Have a so called "transit object" which carries pointers/references to the real instances and supplies getters.

```
class TransitObject
{
    private:
        MyGarden&   garden;
        MyApple&    apple;
        MyFountain& fountain;
    public:
        TransitObject(MyGarden& G, MyApple& A, MyFountain& F) : garden(G), apple(A), fountain(F) {}
        MyApple& GetApple() { return apple; }
        MyGarden& GetGarden() { return garden; }
        MyFountain& GetFountain() { return fountain; }
};

class WoodShack
{
    public:
        WoodShack(TransitObject& t) { t.GetApple().whatever(); }
};
```

Do you think this is an advantage? I like it because it makes carrying singletons arround very easy. Adding new instances is quite easy and does not confuse the programmer. Note that the code is just an example and could of course be optimized (const, destructor, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to reinvent a wheel. What you presented looks very like the [builder design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), and you can even find a c++ examples on the net ([here](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder/cpp/1) and [here](https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1121152)).

Comment: I'm not a big fan of pattern names, it might be possible that there is a similarity to the builder pattern though. Basically I'm checking if this concept makes sense.